# I cannot use module Alamofire in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, version, alamofire

I am trying to build a project in Xcode version 9.2 . I had to change the version of SWIFT to 3.2 and now I got the following error : No such module "Alamofire".
I have tried : sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
cd location
pod install && open MyProject.xcworkspace .
I also tried Clean project but none of them work. I am new in iOS developing, can somebody help me out ?

Answer (score -1):

Recently Apple Developer did some changes, one of them is you cannot use some pods with a free developer account. You need to have a paid developer account.

Comment: Can you provide any sort of documentation on this claim?